# How to solve a functional equation using the $W$ function?

Tags: functions, exponential-function, lambert-w

The equation to solve:

$$a^x+bf(x)+c = 0$$

Where $f(x)$ is a polynomial equation of degree $n$ without a constant term as it is covered by $c$.

I have solved the case where $f(x) = x$:

$$a^x+bx+c = 0$$

$$x_{1} = -\frac{c}{b} - \frac{W_{0}\big(\frac{(a^{\frac{-c}{b}})}{b}\big)}{ln(a)}$$

$$x_{2} = -\frac{c}{b} - \frac{W_{-1}\big(\frac{(a^{\frac{-c}{b}})}{b}\big)}{ln(a)}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If $f(x)$ is a polynomial consisting of multiple powers of $x$, then it won't be possible to solve this equation using the Lambert $W$ function: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4699617/solving-b-at-c-a2t-d-t-at-e-t2-f-t-g-0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a^x+bf(x)+c=0\tag{1}$$

$$a^x+bx^n+c=0$$

You already applied Lambert W for $n=1$.

**a)**

We can apply Lambert W also for $(n\neq 1) \land (c=0)$.

for real $a,b,x$; $k\in\{-1,0\}$:

$$a^x+bx^n=0$$
$$e^{\ln(a)x}+bx^n=0$$
$$e^{\ln(a)x}=-bx^n$$
$$1=-bx^ne^{-\ln(a)x}$$
$$-bx^ne^{-\ln(a)x}=1$$
$$x^ne^{-\ln(a)x}=-\frac{1}{b}$$
$$xe^{-\frac{\ln(a)}{n}x}=\left(-\frac{1}{b}\right)^\frac{1}{n}$$
$$-\frac{\ln(a)}{n}xe^{-\frac{\ln(a)}{n}x}=-\frac{\ln(a)}{n}\left(-\frac{1}{b}\right)^\frac{1}{n}$$
$$-\frac{\ln(a)}{n}x=W_k\left(-\frac{\ln(a)}{n}\left(-\frac{1}{b}\right)^\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
$$x=-\frac{n}{\ln(a)}W_k\left(-\frac{\ln(a)}{n}\left(-\frac{1}{b}\right)^\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

**b)**

Your general equation (1) can be solved in terms of Generalized Lambert W.